# Page refresh working fine with HTTP while giving 404 not found error with https for same url used in angularjs app

Tags: .htaccess, angularjs, https

I created a website using Angularjs. all the pages working fine with http and https except user page. I have created a user.html in a templates folder and route that page correctly but when I use that route using https, it gives 404 page not found error while working fine with http. It gives only after refresh the page for that URL.

I have set the mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` file but all the pages except user is working fine with http and https during refresh.

Comment: Post your current .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Are you sure DOCUMENT_ROOT of https is same http site?

Comment: yes DOCUMENT_ROOT for https is same as http.

Comment: ok can you show current rules in your .htaccess?